# packages that improve the magit history graph when running in graphical modes

Tags: magit

Are there any modes that improve how the history graph is drawn?
it would be nice to find something that:

1. coloured the lines to visually distinguish them
2. used unicode or other graphical fancyness to connect the lines more cleanly
3. other fancy looking things i haven't thought of!

Comment: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2989

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. That already exists and is only disabled for performance reasons. To enable it enter the log popup <kbd>l</kbd>, enable the respective switch <kbd>- c</kbd>, and save that as the default <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>.
2. That used to exist, but I removed it when I noticed that it had been severely broken for a year or so without anyone complaining about it (and how difficult it would be to fix it).
3. Fancier log graphs are [in planning](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2989).